# How do I load 'inline' javascript dynamically from WebDriver

Tags: jquery, webdriver

I am implementing some AXAJ tests that I code against WebDriver API. Over it, I could execute arbitrary javascript code but I need to make some custom utility functions available for any further references in my tests. 
The problem is that I need to dynamically load my "inline" custom javascript that resides in a file at my client classpath. So I could not use the usual approach that depends on manipulating script.src. I tried to manipulate script.text but with no success, I get a javascript error like: "missing ; before statement".
Do you see anything wrong with my approach ?. Any other ideas how to do this ?

```
private static final String LOAD_DYNAMIC_JS = 
"(function(){" + 
"var em = document.createElement('script'); em.type = 'text/javascript';" +
"em.text=\"<![CDATA[" +
"function testalert(){" +
"alert(\"test\");" +
//"}" +
"]]>\";" +
"var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(em, s);"+
"})();"; 
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(LOAD_DYNAMIC_JS);
```

**EDIT**
Actually my example was incorrect. Because in practice, I am loading the injected script from file residing in the classpath. And the script there is formatted with newlines. 
So the problem was exactly as the error message says: "...missing ;". This is because the script I try to assign to script.text is actually a string literal for the enclosing function(). And string literals in javascript could not stretch on several lines unless they end with '\' character. Additionally, while debugging I realized that the enclosing function() is not necessary as webdriver already does so to inject the javascript in the browser. The CDATA section is also not necessary. So my inline injection script that finally worked is:

```
private static final String LOAD_DYNAMIC_JS = 
"var em = document.createElement('script'); em.type = 'text/javascript';" +
"em.text= 'function testalert(){alert('test');};'"+
"var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(em, s);";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(LOAD_DYNAMIC_JS);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(LOAD_DYNAMIC_JS);
```

To this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("{" + LOAD_DYNAMIC_JS + "}");
```

It should work perfectly...

If you aren't executing a single statement, then WebDriver needs the script to be wrapped in curly braces.